# Написание демона на php или другой способ подскажите, плиз

Tags: php, mysql, linux

У меня большая таблица А в 4 гб (строк 46549259), и делая выборки из других таблиц, мне надо залить в таблицу С. 
Индексы в таблице А проставлены. 1 запрос составляет 1,657с.

Пробовала делать демон по статье http://bx-cert.ru/advices/50/realizatsiya-prostogo-demona-na-php/

У меня виртуальная машина centos. На хостинге боюсь запустить демон, не уверена еще... Вот я скопировала код.

```
<?$stop = false;
/**
* pcntl_fork() - данная функция разветвляет текущий процесс
*/
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid == -1) {
/**
 * Не получилось сделать форк процесса, о чем сообщим в консоль
 */
die('Error fork process' . PHP_EOL);
} elseif ($pid) {
/**
 * В эту ветку зайдет только родительский процесс, который мы убиваем и сообщаем об этом в консоль
 */
die('Die parent process' . PHP_EOL);
} else {
/**
 * Бесконечный цикл
 */

while(!$stop) {
    /*
     * Тело демона
     */
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        file_put_contents('/var/data/tmp/' . $i . '.txt', time());
        sleep(2);
    }
}
}
/**
 * Установим дочерний процесс основным, это необходимо для создания процессов
 */
posix_setsid();

?>
```

и сохранила под названием daemon.php .Сунула в папку `/var/data/`
в папке виртуальной машины `var` не было `data`,создала эту папку. Зашла в консоль виртуалки и написала команду `/usr/bin/php /var/data/daemon.php & > /dev/null`
виртуалка показала процесс и слово "Stopped". а сам демон не выполнился, нет 
10 файлов в папке `/var/data/tmp/`? почему? Если скинете мне примерчик демона, буду очень благодарна!
я не знаю что мне делать. Мне достаточно делать в моем случае(перенос таблицы) однопроцессорный демон как по этой статье, или нужен многопроцессорный демон?

Comment: С демонами надо быть осторожнее. Нужно следить чтобы не было утечек памяти.
А чем Вам не подходит скрипт который будет запускаться по крону и обрабатывать по 20-30 записей?

Comment: Спасибо за мысль, я уже не надеялась получить ответ. И я пробовала запустить в режиме norup. Скрипт обрабатывает у меня по лимитам.  То есть если в таблице у меня 46549259 строк, поэтому я задала первый этап обработки 300000 строк. Но запрос обрабатывает по лимитам по этим строкам. У меня не хватило памяти на диске, как пишет лог "Got error 28 from storage engine". Я не представляю," как обрабатывать 20-30 записей". Это лимит в запросе, или сам скрипт содержащий 20-30 записей?

Comment: Если последнее, я правильно понимаю, что скрипт надо запускать с параметрами?